# drop all lines where a value in column 1 is of type float

Tags: python, csv

I am looking for a way to drop all lines where the value in the first column is of type "nan" or "float"

```
bad_words = ['nan']
counter=0
with open('data_sentiment_stripped_emoticons.csv',"r", encoding="utf-8") as oldfile, \
     open('data_final.csv', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            counter +=int(1)
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
print(counter)
```

the problem with this solution is that it also deletes lines that contain nan in words.

file part:

```
""USERNAME ob ich nachschlagen will, was das auf deutsch heisst? "",4
""USERNAME hier kommen grade einige Erinnerungen vom vor 8 Jahren hoch und es ist sehr gut "",4
""USERNAME Du meinst mein Profilbild? Er heiÃŸt Paul "",4
""USERNAME ich kann dir sagen, dass ZukunftsÃ¤ngste besser werden mit der Zeit, weil du begreifst, dass es immer einen Weg gibt "",4
""Wenn YouTube einen abfuckt  URL",0
```

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: you don't need to do `newfile.close()` when you use a context manager. But could you share a part of your file? Also what is the seperator of your csv-file?

Comment: @itzMEonTV: I read it, but how shall that help?

Comment: @MSeifert:I removed newfile.close().

Comment: And the part of the file? The seperator of your file?

Comment: Added the file part. The seperator is ","

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Also, there appears to be a missing `"` on the last line of the file part—is that intentional? Finally, are there any lines in the file part that should be dropped? You should show your expected output.

Comment: When you say "column 1" are you counting from zero or one?

Comment: For better future SO interaction - you may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

your sample csv data looks strange. it doesn't have any nansthe doubled double-quotes means line 1 has 3 columns and line 4 has five.

depending on the actual format, you could try starts with if you want to match the start of the line

```
if any([line.startswith(word) for word in badwords]):
    counter++
else:
    newfile.write(line)
```